# Is a converging sequence a special case of a continuous function?

Tags: general-topology, convergence-divergence, continuity

If we look at topology categorically, as the study of topological spaces and continuous functions, I wonder how converging sequences fit in, as they are not directly mentioned. I find it a bit odd that you have the two notions of convergence and continuity that are introduced more or less separately from another as a consequence of having just one structure.

A sequence $a$ is a function $a : \mathbb{N} \to M$ for some topological space $(M, τ)$, but $\mathbb{N}$ of course has a topology itself (the discrete topology would be the natural one, I guess, but maybe others are better?), allowing us to speak about continuity. So, I wonder if continuity of $a$ is in any way meaningful and how convergence is related to that.

If, instead, continuity and convergence are in fact separate things that coincidentally fall out of the theory independently, I wonder if there are other structures that actually separate these two concepts, i. e. are there structures in which you can talk about continuity but not about convergence and vice versa?

Comment: A convergent sequence in $X$ is a continuous function $f\colon\omega+1\to X$ (where $\omega+1$ has the order topology)

Comment: "are there structures in which you can talk about continuity but not about convergence" like 99% of topology is about continuity without convergence (at least of sequences). For convergence without topology have a look at: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_space